# Check if an any key/value does not exists in an object (with pure js)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So let's say this is my object:

```
var data = {
  key1 : 'a',
  key2 : 'b',
  key3 : 'c'
};
```

And I have a function that loads my default settings like this:

```
function defaults() {
  data.key1 = 'a';
  data.key2 = 'b';
  data.key3 = 'c';
  data.key4 = 'd';
}
```

How can I check if any of the 'default' values are missing?

Comment: please share the **data** which you want to iterate through

Comment: Okay, I've updated the question.

Comment: Your question asks for pure js, but you've tagged jquery?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the tag. I thought I was supposed to tag anything that the question was about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is tagged jQuery the easiest would be use [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to merge two objects

```js
var data = {
  key1 : 'xxxxxxxx'  
}

var defaults = {
  key1 : 'a',
  key2 : 'b',
  key3 : 'c'
};

var results = $.extend(defaults,data);

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In plain JS

```
  for( key in defaults){
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key) && defaults.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        data[key] = defaults[key];
    }
  }
```

Comment: This seems awesome, but I need pure js. I'm sorry I tagged jquery, I'm new to this. I really really like this solution though. This is better than what I'm looking for. I just need to figure out how to do it without jquery.

Comment: Ok...simple to convert...give me couple of minutes.

Comment: Updated with plain js approach

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

data.key1 = data.key1 || 'a';

Loads what's already there. If it's null or undefined or false in any way it loads 'a'

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following.
But someone already posted=)

```
var data = {
    key1: 'a'
};
var data_default = {
    key1: 'a',
    key2: 'b',
    key3: 'c',
    key4: 'd'
};

function defaults() {
    for (var key in data_default) {
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key) || data[key] == "") {
            data[key] = data_default[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`object.hasOwnProperty` can check the object key is exist.You have default function ,to access this data you need to do return.

```
var data = {
  key1 : 'a',
  key2 : 'b',
  key3 : 'c'
};
function defaults() {
  d = {};
  d.key1 = 'a';
  d.key2 = 'b';
  d.key3 = 'c';
  d.key4 = 'd';
  return d;
}
var object = defaults();
var miss = [];
for(var i in object){   
    if(!data.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        miss.push(i);
    }
}
console.log(miss);
```